# Logo image can be made responsive but doesn't work in a div

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to make my logo image responsive. So that it will get bigger or smaller according to screen size. It works if I use max-width in the image while no height and width are given in the div it is in. I could keep it that way but the image size is a lot bigger than I want. On the other hand, image responsiveness does not work if I use height and width in the div.

This is what I tried till now.

HTML

```
<div class="nav-sidebar">
    <div id="logo">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="images/backgrounds/logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="logo1" id="matin">
            <span class="notranslate">MATIN</span>
            <span class="shade">&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="logo2" id="int">
            <span class="notranslate">INTERNATIONAL</span>
            <span class="shade">&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.nav-sidebar #logo .logo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    top: -47%;
    left: 30%;
}

.logo img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: `position: absolute;` will break responsiveness.

Comment: Should I use margin instead?

Comment: Can you please share reference what kind of structure you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Media Queries, so that for a specified minimum screen width (or height), you can change CSS properties. In your case, that would be the `height`, and `width` of the Logo Image:

```html
<div class="nav-sidebar">
    <div id="logo">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="images/backgrounds/logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="logo1" id="matin">
            <span class="notranslate">MATIN</span>
            <span class="shade">&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="logo2" id="int">
            <span class="notranslate">INTERNATIONAL</span>
            <span class="shade">&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```css
.nav-sidebar #logo .logo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    top: -47%;
    left: 30%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px){
    .logo img {
        width: 110px;
        height: 110px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1366px){
    .logo img {
        width: 130px;
        height: 130px;
    }

@media screen and (min-width: 1920px){
    .logo img {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }
}
```

NOTE: The Example wrote makes the width/height of the image 110px, when the screen (viewport) is a minimum width of 480px, 130px when the minimum screen width is 1366px (quite common for browsing laptops), and 150px for a screen that has a minimum width of 1920px (common for desktop monitors). Keep in mind that this feature doesn't specifically apply just to images, you can scale anything with this.